# create google sheet with multiple worksheets

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I try to use google drive api to create a google sheets into specify folder. My following code works fine except I would like to create a file with multiple worksheets. I have tried to `properties`. However, it still show as  `Sheet1`

```
file_metadata = {'properties': {'title': 'test title'}, 'name': 'google sheets filename', 'parents': [google_folder_id], 'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet', }
google_sheets_metadata = self.__service.files().create(body=file_metadata).execute()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- You want to create new Spreadsheet to the specific folder.
- You want to create new Spreadsheet by creating multiple worksheets.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis with python.
- You have already been able to use Drive API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Issue and workaround:

Drive API can directly create the Spreadsheet. But in this case, the Spreadsheet cannot be created with the multiple sheets. So in this case, Sheets API is required to be also used.

Before you use the following scripts, please enable Sheets API. And please add `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets` to the scopes. In this case, please delete the credential file (`token.pickle`) including the access token and refresh token and authorize again. By this, the new scopes are reflected. Please be careful this.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, after the Spreadsheet is created to the specific folder using the create method of Drive API, 2 worksheets are added to the created Spreadsheet using the method of batchUpdate of Sheets API.

#### Sample script:

```
sheets = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
drive = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

google_folder_id = '###'
file_metadata = {'properties': {'title': 'test title'}, 'name': 'google sheets filename', 'parents': [google_folder_id], 'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'}
google_sheets_metadata = drive.files().create(body=file_metadata).execute()
fileId = google_sheets_metadata['id']
body = {"requests": [{"addSheet": {}}, {"addSheet": {"properties": {"title": "sampleSheet"}}}]}
res = sheets.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=fileId, body=body).execute()
print(res)
```

- In this case, the 3rd sheet name is `sampleSheet` as a sample.

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, after the Spreadsheet is created to the root folder with 3 worksheets using the method of create of Sheets API, the created Spreadsheet is moved to the specific folder using the method of update of Drive API.

#### Sample script:

```
sheets = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
drive = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

google_folder_id = '###'
body = {"properties": {"title": "sampleSpreadsheet"}, "sheets": [{}, {}, {"properties": {"title": "sampleSheet"}}]}
res = sheets.spreadsheets().create(body=body).execute()
spreadsheetId = res['spreadsheetId']
google_sheets_metadata = drive.files().update(fileId=spreadsheetId, removeParents='root', addParents=google_folder_id).execute()
```

- In this case, the 3rd sheet name is `sampleSheet` as a sample.

### Note:

- In above scripts, it supposes that your script for authorizing works.

### References:

- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [Method: spreadsheets.create](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create)
- [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

### Added:

When you want to use the pattern 1 and you want to give the sheet names of "a" and "b" to the 1st and 2nd tabs, the script is as follows.

When new Spreadsheet is created using Drive API, the created Spreadsheet has 1st tab. So in your case, it is required to rename the 1st sheet to "a" and add one sheet with the name of "b".

```
sheets = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
drive = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

google_folder_id = '###'
file_metadata = {'properties': {'title': 'test title'}, 'name': 'google sheets filename', 'parents': [google_folder_id], 'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'}
google_sheets_metadata = drive.files().create(body=file_metadata).execute()
fileId = google_sheets_metadata['id']

title = [{"addSheet": {"properties": {"title": name}}} for name in set(['b'])]
title.append({"updateSheetProperties": {"fields": "title", "properties": {"title": "a", "index": 0}}})
body = {"requests": title}
res = sheets.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=fileId, body=body).execute()
print(res)
```

Comment: it is great answer, however, I use following code,         ```title = [{"addSheet": {"properties": {"title": name}}} for name in set(['a', 'b'])]
        body = {"requests": title}
        response = self.__service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=google_sheets_file_id, body=body).execute()
``` i create 3 sheets and "Sheet1" and 'a' and 'b'..but i only want "a" and "b"

Comment: @jacobcan118 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, I apologize again.

Comment: @jacobcan118 Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: i have another google api question but unrelated to this questions and can I ask you offline? @Tanaike

Comment: @jacobcan118 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I would like to support you. So can you post it as new question? By this, a lot of users including me can think of your issue.

Comment: sure, thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60657942/access-google-drive-api-from-docker