# How to access Google Drive API from Docker?

Tags: docker, google-sheets, google-drive-api

How can I bypass the consent screen pop up from the browser when working with Gogle Drive API? So far I am using OAuth2.0 to get authorization from Google API, but that will pop up a consent screen to ask you allow API access on your account and create a token on your local environment.

However, I would like to move all parts of the application into Docker and I do not want to publish the token file into the Docker image.

Is there any workaround to do that?

Comment: In your situation, how about using the service account instead of OAuth2? Or how about using Web Apps as an API? By this, the authorization code is not required to be retrieved. So it is not required to open the browser. But I'm not sure about your actual situation. So if this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: How about requiring passing the token as an environment variable when running your image as a Docker container? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#environment-variables. You don't need to include it in build-time, only in run-time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using service account credentials might work , but the disadvantage is that we will not be able to see those files in drive account , but we will be able to access them using api

Comment: The question was about how to specify the credentials of an account as part of building the Docker image. This answer can be improved by describing how to do that with a service account.

Comment: The function methods or google api update everytime , I just wanted tell that there is a way to bypass user consent using service account , the method which I followed might get depreciated later , its best if we follow the documentation